# Why dialout not vagrant is the owner of shared files

Tags: laravel-4, vagrant

I have a homestead vagrant setup with the file sharing configuration below:

```
# Register All Of The Configured Shared Folders
settings["folders"].each do |folder|
  config.vm.synced_folder folder["map"], folder["to"], type: folder["type"] ||= nil, nfs: true, :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']
end
```

After that, the ownership of shared files become `dialout` from `vagrant`. Is it the reason why I am getting `502 Bad Gateway` on ajax request?